# Having trouble with form validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble figuring out how to validate my form, how do I validate the firstname so that when I click submit and it is empty it will come up with error.

I have tried a few different ways of coding but i am very new to javascript and cant figure it out

Please let me know how to fix it as I am really struggling with javascript

```js
function validateForm(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    document.forms('sightingform');
    document.getElementById("firsname").value;
    document.getElementById("lasname").value;
    document.getElementById("animalclass").selectedIndex;
    
if(firsname.value.length == 0){
    document.getElementById('head').innerText = "* All fields are mandatory *";
    firsname.focus();
    return false;

}
```

```html
        <form class="form-group" id="sightingform" >
            <fieldset>
                    <label class="block" for="firstName" >First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="firsname" name="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your First Name...">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                    <label class="block" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lasname" name="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Last Name...">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                    <label class="block" for="mobile">Mobile Telephone Number</label>
                    <input type="tel" name="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your mobile number...">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label class="block" for="animal">Class of Animal</label>
                <select name="animals" class="form-control">
                    <option value="select">Select Animal</option>
                    <option value="amphibians">Amphibians</option>
                    <option value="arthropods">Arthropods</option>
                    <option value="birds">Birds</option>
                    <option value="fish">Fish</option>
                    <option value="mammals">Select Animal</option>
                    <option value="reptiles">Reptiles</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="sighting" class="block">Date of Sighting</label>
                <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="time" class="block">Time of Sighting</label>
                <input type="time" name="time" class="form-control">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="desc" class="block">Description</label>
                <textarea row="3" cols="30" name="desc" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter description of the sighted animal..."></textarea>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="state">
                <label for="sighting" class="block">State</label>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">QLD
                </item>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">NSW
                </item>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3">VIC
                </item>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4">WA
                </item>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5">SA
                </item>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6">NT
                </item>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox7">ACT
                </item>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="nearest-town" class="block">Nearest Town</label>
                <input type="text" name="town" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the nearest town...">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="validateForm(event)" value="Submit Sighting">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? What is happening that shouldn't? What isn't happening that should? Do you have any console errors that need fixing?

Answer (score 1):

There are some issue with your code

- Missing } after function
- Use name instead of id for form `forms['sightingform']`
- Did not declare variable firsname
- animalclass not found in HTML => undefined
- Dont have head id in HTML

```js
function validateForm(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    document.forms['sightingform'];
    var firsname = document.getElementById("firsname");
    document.getElementById("lasname").value;
    //document.getElementById("animalclass").selectedIndex;
    
if(firsname.value.length == 0){
    document.getElementById('head').innerText = "* All fields are mandatory *";
    firsname.focus();
    return false;
}
}
```

```html
<form class="form-group" name="sightingform" >
<h3 id='head'></h3>
            <fieldset>
                    <label class="block" for="firstName" >First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="firsname" name="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your First Name...">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                    <label class="block" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lasname" name="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Last Name...">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                    <label class="block" for="mobile">Mobile Telephone Number</label>
                    <input type="tel" name="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your mobile number...">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label class="block" for="animal">Class of Animal</label>
                <select name="animals" class="form-control">
                    <option value="select">Select Animal</option>
                    <option value="amphibians">Amphibians</option>
                    <option value="arthropods">Arthropods</option>
                    <option value="birds">Birds</option>
                    <option value="fish">Fish</option>
                    <option value="mammals">Select Animal</option>
                    <option value="reptiles">Reptiles</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="sighting" class="block">Date of Sighting</label>
                <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="time" class="block">Time of Sighting</label>
                <input type="time" name="time" class="form-control">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="desc" class="block">Description</label>
                <textarea row="3" cols="30" name="desc" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter description of the sighted animal..."></textarea>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="state">
                <label for="sighting" class="block">State</label>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">QLD
                </item>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">NSW
                </item>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3">VIC
                </item>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4">WA
                </item>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5">SA
                </item>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6">NT
                </item>
                <item  class="inline form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox7">ACT
                </item>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="nearest-town" class="block">Nearest Town</label>
                <input type="text" name="town" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the nearest town...">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="validateForm(event)" value="Submit Sighting">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```